# Getting Actual Facebook and Twitter Profile Image URLS for Flex Security Policy

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter

I'm trying to display the profile images from both facebook and twitter. For facebook, the URLs I'm receiving are something like this (not actual urls):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/965412145/picture
```

Which is then redirected to the 'actual' url like this:

```
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/370471_9631690_1796253478_r.jpg
```

I'm also doing this with twitter, with the same issue (redirected url).

So, when I load the image, it loads fine. But when I close the container that the image is in, then I get the security sandbox violation.

I can get this all to work if I add the URL from the 'actual' image url like this:

```
request = new URLRequest("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net");
loader = new Loader();
context = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
loader.load(request, context);
```

However, at run time, I do not actually know what the 'actual' image url is, so I can't hard-code that domain in (nor do I want to).

Is there a way to get the actual url (from within flex) of the image so that I can add the correct domain to the loadercontext?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you're trying to load an image from a URL that redirects to another source.  You need to know what the *redirected* URL is, so you can load a policy file that allow manipulation of image bytes.

If I've understood correctly, you need to detect the redirected URL by listening for the `COMPLETE` event (or an error event), then reference the `LoaderInfo.url` property.  This property will reflect the end URL in the event of redirects.  For example, you would have code like this in the listener:

```
var ldr:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
var url:String;
try
{
    url = ldr.url;
    // Split off URL base, load policy file, etc here
}
catch (e:Error)
{
    // Unable to detect final URL due to error.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks so much! I also found documentation for this at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#checkPolicyFile.

Comment: @swatkins Good link.  I think that redirection explanation may be new, as I don't remember seeing it in years gone by.  Glad to help!