# Flex ignoring policy file

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, twitter

I'm loading in profile images from both facebook and twitter into a flex application. Based on the answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7896115/844726), I'm loading the domain policy from the **redirected** url. However, now I'm seeing this error:

```
Error: [strict] Ignoring policy file at http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/ due 
to missing Content-Type.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files 
to fix this problem.
```

The crossdomain.xml file from that URL looks like this:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="*"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The error states that there is a missing Content-Type. How do I get around this? I, obviously, can't update facebook's files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code from your other question:

```
request = new URLRequest("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net");
loader = new Loader();
context = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
loader.load(request, context);
```

You need to set the `URLRequest` to load from http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml instead of just http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net .  If you inspect the headers returned from the latter request (which really should fail), it doesn't send any `Content-type` header.  However, the http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml file does send a proper `Content-type: text/xml` header.

So, you should use:

```
request = new URLRequest("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
loader = new Loader();
context = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
loader.load(request, context);
```